# how to correctly download a json file from github using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download what is suppose to be a json file hosted in some github repo. Here's the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aavail/ai-workflow-capstone/master/cs-train/invoices-2017-11.json).

The problem is that when i try to decode the json with python i'm having the following error:

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

This sounds like an incorrect json formatting, so i when manually open the file in an editor, this is what i see:

[image]

This is not a json file, but that is what is supposed to be. Instead, i'm getting this tree-structured file. I need to load this into a `dataframe` using `pandas`. Could somebody please point me in the right direction here? what am i doing wrong?

This is the code i have used to get that file:

```
import urllib.request as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url = r.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aavail/ai-workflow-capstone/master/cs-train/invoices-2017-11.json")
content = url.read()
soup = bs(content)
newDictionary=json.loads(str(soup))
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Congrats! 1000 rep.

Comment: Thank you @AnnZen !! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instead, i'm getting this tree-structured file.

Nope, I promise you're getting a JSON file ;).  The tree-structured represtation is your browser making the file look pretty for you.  If you `curl -XGET -L <url>`, you'll see what is very much a JSON string.

Pandas allows you to read JSON from a URL directly:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aavail/ai-workflow-capstone/master/cs-train/invoices-2017-11.json"
>>> df = pd.read_json(url)
>>> df.head()
          country  customer_id invoice  price stream_id  times_viewed  year  month  day
0  United Kingdom      13085.0  489434   6.95     85048            12  2017     11   28
1  United Kingdom          NaN  489597   8.65     22130             1  2017     11   28
2  United Kingdom          NaN  489597   1.70     22132             6  2017     11   28
3  United Kingdom          NaN  489597   1.70     22133             4  2017     11   28
4  United Kingdom          NaN  489597   0.87     22134             1  2017     11   28
```